# Roximity iBeacon gives error "ERROR: Failed to begin ranging beacons"

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-bluetooth

We bought few iBeacon devices from Roximity and now trying to set them up and write a sample application to receive notifications sent by it. We also used the sample application on Github under https://github.com/roximity/ROXIMITYSDKStarterKit-iOS to test.

When we run the app, all we can see are the following log messages and nothing more.

2014-04-28 08:49:15.817 RoximityMyApp[5172:60b] ROXIMITY SDK Version: 1.1.51
2014-04-28 08:49:16.726 RoximityMyApp[5172:60b] ERROR: Failed to begin ranging beacons
2014-04-28 08:49:16.814 RoximityMyApp[5172:60b] ERROR: Failed to begin ranging beacons
2014-04-28 08:49:16.827 RoximityMyApp[5172:60b] ERROR: Failed to begin ranging beacons
2014-04-28 08:49:16.830 RoximityMyApp[5172:60b] ERROR: Failed to begin ranging beacons

Comment: Do you have the Bluetooth radio turned on and location services enabled?

Comment: @Stonz2 Yes, it picks up other Bluetooth devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to answer my own question, so it seems there is an issue in the device I am using. Earlier I was using iPhone 4 but this is being supported on devices iPhone 4S and above. Also, there was an issue in my Bluetooth antenna where it randomly drops the connection, might be the case with that when I tried with a 4S.
Hope this will help someone else.